# Loop login - /tmp permission issue

Tags: permissions, login, snap, login-screen

I am facing loop login issue on Ubuntu 22.10.

I was able to log into the shell and observed the following `/tmp` permissions:

`drwxr-xr-x  20 arnaud arnaud  60K mars  24 08:55 tmp`

I was able work around it by running in the shell the following commands:

```
chmod 1777 /tmp
sudo chown root:root /tmp
sudo service gdm3 restart
```

Though, every time the computer is rebooted, I face the issue again.

I suspect an issue with snap. After login, when I try to run a snap installed software, I get this error
`/tmp/snap-private-tmp has unexpected ownership / permissions: File exists`. Actually, I can see that `/tmp/snap-private-tmp` has only subfolder,`snap.snapd-desktop-integration`

After removing folder `/tmp/snap-private-tmp`, I can run the program, but the problem happens again after reboot.

Any thoughts why `/tmp` permissions are screwed at each boot?

Comment: You messed with a system folder permissions. tmp. Never mess with system folders in this manner. Deleting the folder and letting the system recreate it fixed that one.  You could try removing the unnamed snap software and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I have not changed the `/tmp` permissions before the issue happened, and each reboot its permissions are screwed again.
I edited the question to mention that `snap.snapd-desktop-integration` is present in `/tmp/snap-private-tmp` at startup

Comment: The creation of /tmp (and subdirectories therein) is now controlled by systemd-tmpfiles, based on configuration files in `/etc/tmpfiles.d/` and `/lib/tmpfiles.d/` - so check there for "rogue" directives (ex. `grep -r arnaud /lib/tmpfiles.d/`)

Comment: Read `man hier`, the Filesystem Hieracy Standard. Your use of `/tmp` may be confusing to your system. Is there another directory you could use? Read `man mkdir`.

Comment: @steeldriver yeah,  `systemd-tmpfiles` seemed to be a good thing to check. Though,I could not find any rogue directives anywhere. 
The good thing is that I don't face the issue anymore. I don't know why it got fixed (maybe a package update)